# Batch file to move files if content search string matches

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a small batch to search for strings in text files and the files that contain this string are moved to a folder created next, at least that's how it should work, does anyone know what it is?

**Commands**

```
@echo off

Echo FIND STRING AND MOVE FILES TO FOLDER

Echo.

set /p word=Search for: 
set /p folder=Folder Name: 

md %folder%

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /i /m "%word%" "*.txt"') DO (
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 MOVE %%a %folder% > Nul

Echo Done!

}

pause
```

**Files to Move to Folder**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPDuc.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix for your supplied script:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo FIND STRING AND MOVE FILES TO FOLDER
Echo(

Set/P "word=Search for: "
Set/P "folder=Folder Name: "

If Not Exist "%folder%\" MD "%folder%" 2>Nul||Exit/B

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr/ILMC:"%word%" *.txt 2^>Nul'
) Do Move "%%~A" "%folder%">Nul

Echo Done!

Pause
```

*Bear in mind that any script which asks for user input and which doesn't have a relatively robust method in place to protect your system from deliberate or accidental input is potentially dangerous.*

Comment: Work very well, Thanks!